# Symfony4 docker doctrine does not create database

Tags: php, docker, doctrine-orm, docker-compose, symfony4

I got some error when I tried to create my Database, I have already do all the configuration in the `.env` and `doctrine.yaml` but I still have errors.

I use Docker, PostegreSQL, Symfony4.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide us with your docker configuration. This is common issue with docker as you must understand how networks work.

Comment: what configuration you want please ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use db as your named host, but if your docker container that holds website is in separate network you will receive error of unresolved network name.
Please read this https://blog.docker.com/2016/12/understanding-docker-networking-drivers-use-cases/
and make sure your website is in same network as database container.

Comment: i read this but i can't make sure that my website is in same network as database container :/

Comment: macbook-pro-de-nirojan:feedback nirojanthasan$  docker network create -d bridge mybridge

Error response from daemon: network with name mybridge already exists
macbook-pro-de-nirojan:feedback nirojanthasan$ 
macbook-pro-de-nirojan:feedback nirojanthasan$  docker run -d --net mybridge --name db redis
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/db" is already in use by container "44f5c8af7e0455caf5a0662e2bb7bd9d0b3c7d22374d6a0cc80153a2622b5aa5". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

Comment: docker-compose ps
      Name                    Command              State            Ports          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
feedback_db_1      docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Up      0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp  
feedback_nginx_1   nginx -g daemon off;            Up      0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp    
feedback_php_1     docker-entrypoint php-fpm       Up      127.0.0.1:9090->9000/tcp

Comment: @NirojanThasan delete the container that named db and create it again with your new network configuration or use `docker network connect` to make a running container join a network. then use `docker inspect` to check the ip

Comment: thank you for your time what i have to add, is that docker network connect db ?

Comment: yes , check the following to get the correct command: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/

Comment: do you use docker-compose? Try docker-compose if you are beginner. It will be easier to understand and you can set network for every container specifically.